# porque mi consulta sql no funciona?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Buen día para todos, tengo el siguiente formulario en html:

```
          <form action="pagar.php" method="POST">
         
         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $f->clave; ?>" name="clave" size="40">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $f->nombre; ?>" name="nombre" size="40">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['precio'] ?>" name="total" size="40">
          <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar cliente">
          </form>`
```

que lo lleno con valores de una consulta en mysql, y estos a su ves los mando a otra pagina para procesar los datos en  una nueva consulta sql, la cual no me funciona, el código de la segunda pestaña es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas2");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("No se puede conectar a la base de datos:" . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    
}
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];


   echo  $clave ;
   echo $nombre;
     echo $total;
    $insertar="INSERT INTO `tblventas`
    (`id`, `fecha`, `nombre`, `total`, `clave`) 
    VALUES 
    ('1', 'CURDATE()', '$nombre', '$total', '$clave');";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conn, $insertar);

    if (!$resultado) {
        ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
alert("¡ Error al registrar venta!");
window.location.href='';

</script>

 <?php

        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("!venta registrada!");
   window.location.href='clientes.php';
   </script>
     <?php
    

    mysqli_close($conn);
 }

?>
```

Ya verifiqué que los datos enviados por el método post si se esten recibiendo, solo que la sentencia no se ejecuta, igual que la conexión a la base de datos si se esta realizando, ya probé de diferentes maneras y no me funciona, por su ayuda gracias.

Comment: El campo `id` de la tabla acepta nulos?

Comment: el valor del id es autoincrementable y llave primaria de la tabla, asi lo he realizado así en ocasiones anteriores y si me funcionaba, solo que esta ves algo realice diferente que no me funciona.

Comment: la sentencia para crear la tabla es esta: REATE TABLE `tblventas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(60,0) NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

Comment: te manda algun error?

Comment: no retorna ningun error, solo se va al else y no ejecuta la sentencia... y no se como mostrar si es que existe un error al ejecutar la sentecia

Comment: Si `id` es autoincrementable entonces no debe ir ese campo en el insert.

Comment: modificando la consulta quedaria así:INSERT INTO `tblventas`
        ( `fecha`, `nombre`, `total`, `clave`) 
        VALUES 
        ( 'CURDATE()', '$nombre', '$total', '$clave');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparando tu dataset con tu consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblventas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(60,0) NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;


INSERT INTO `tblventas`
  (`id`, `fecha`, `correo`, `total`, `clave`) 
  VALUES 
  (NULL, CURDATE(), 'nombre', 'total', 'clave');
```

Se pueden observar dos errores:

- El campo `correo` no existe, deberías usar `nombre`
- El campo `id` no puede contener un valor `NULL` por lo que deberías definirlo como `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` o asingarle valores no nulos.

Algo así, sí funcionaría:

```
INSERT INTO `tblventas`
  (`id`, `fecha`, `nombre`, `total`, `clave`) 
  VALUES 
  (1, CURDATE(), 'nombre', 'total', 'clave');
```

O, incluso mejor así: En primer lugar, modifica una única vez tu tabla para que `id` sea de tipo autoincremental con:

```
ALTER TABLE tblventas 
  MODIFY id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Y, después, ya puedes hacer todas las inserciones que necesites:

```
INSERT INTO `tblventas`
  (`id`, `fecha`, `nombre`, `total`, `clave`) 
  VALUES 
  (NULL, CURDATE(), 'nombre', 'total', 'clave');
```

Comment: Deberías especificar que las consultas `ALTER TABLE` modifican la composición de la tabla, que antes de modificar convendría hacer un backup y que este tipo de consultas se ejecutan una sola vez, si se quiere modificar (alterar) la tabla. Al ponerla seguida del `INSERT`, sin explicar que hace ese tipo de consulta, se podría interpretar que iría siempre junta a cada `INSERT`

Comment: Ok, sí, mejor aclararlo... ya está editada

Comment: volvi a crear la tabla con la sentencia 
CREATE TABLE `tblventas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(60,0) NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci; y posterior a eso ejecute esta sentencia: LTER TABLE `tblventas`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; y ni asi me funciona u.u

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que debugues la consulta con:

```
if (!$resultado) {
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));die;
}
```

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Ya  lo realice, y el problema era que la sentenncia debia quedar asi:  $insertar="INSERT INTO `tblventas`
        (`id`, `fecha`, `nombre`, `total`, `clave`) 
        VALUES 
        (NULL, NOW(), '$nombre', '$total', '$clave');"; y me funciono bastante bien

Comment: Que bueno que solucionaste, gracias gbianchi lo tomaré en cuanta